# Auto press windows key

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Most of you know the `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(string)` or `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(string)` method.  Well, I've been working well with that method until I ran into a problem: How do I programmatically press the Windows key?  Any help is appreciated.  I've tried doing some things but I get an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword "WINDOWS" is not valid.'

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code) it's quite helpful and more explanatory for this question.

update:
this is the other approach.

```
System.windows.forms.keys.LWin;
```

instead of

```
SendKey(string)
```

source : [Enumerated Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It doesn't say how to send the windows key.  I'm looking for the windows key.

Comment: Oh my bad you could use this in place of that way you could do this
System.windows.forms.keys.LWin
update :
this is the Left windows key. 
note :
this is a different approach with an enumerated key list default implemented by Microsoft.

Comment: you simply can't you just have to use this 
{System.windows.forms.keys.LWin} 
instead of 
{... SendKey(string val)}

Comment: How would I use `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.LWin` to auto-press?